# Crystal Reports ASP.NET & SQL Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports-xi

I'm facing an issue with an application to display a report, it shows the login prompt instead.

I want to skip that prompt by saving the password somewhere or disabling this prompt.

But there's not that much documentation about this.

Could you help please

Comment: Is it prompting for a database login or a windows login or a crystal login?

Comment: for the database password because I can't save it with Crystal Reports when configuring the connection

Comment: Does this help? If they do, please post back a detailed answer http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=1021385

Comment: I'm installing business objects to try CMC configuration, Because it seems that it was not necessary for windows server 2008 version of the application

Comment: You can save the password only in crystal reports enterprise version